# how to add 1 decimal place to score system

Tags: android, checkbox

Im trying to make the score of my inspection have 1 decimal place so i can have more precise answer.

```
    result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displaym1score);
    sum=0;
    total=0;


    box1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.box1);
    box1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (box1.isChecked()) {
                sum += 1;      int total = 100*sum/37;
                result.setText(total + "%");
            }
            else {
                sum -= 1;      int total = 100*sum/37;
                result.setText(total + "%");
            }
        }
    });
```

each box you check it updates instantly and the score just needs to have a decimal place like "72.1%" instead of "72%". there is also 36 more boxes set up the same way.

Ive tried a few things and i cannot figure it out. what do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First **total** must be a float or a double, not int

instead setText( ...  put:

```
result.setText(String.format("%.1f", total) + "%");  // 1 is the decimal places you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use a `double` instead of an `int` then format the output to display one decimal place.

Answer (score 0):

use double for total and use following method to get your answer.

```
public double getFormattedTotal(double total){
  DecimalFormat precision = new DecimalFormat("0.0"); 
  return precision.format(total);
}
```